# Change declared variable type in c#

Tags: c#, variables, casting

there.

I have a API which cannot change anything.
what I'm going to do is change the declared variable type in API.

So, I have two variables.

```
string value_API;

var value;

value_API = (string)value;
```

The code above is fine, but I'd like change the type of value_API because the type must follow the type of value.
For example,

```
(int)value_API = value or (double)value_API = API.
```

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Thank you.

P.S. the type of `Value_API` is already defined as string. it isn't accessible to change.

Comment: The code above isn't fine, you can't declare a `var` variable like that.

Comment: [What is the XY Problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @Sayse what does it mean "Can't decalre a var" ?

Comment: First: C# is a language with *static* typing, which means you can´t change a symbols type once declared. This is by design, so you allways know the exact type of a variable, property, method or whatever. Second: why do you think you need to do this? What is the *actual* problem you´re trying to solve?

Comment: `var` only works when the type is known at **compile-time**, which is when you assign a value to it. E.g. `var value = 3`. Here compiler can infer the type of `value` to be of type int. You have to set a value for `value`, otherwise `var` can´t be inferred an actual type.

Comment: if you want to hold different types of data in a variable declare it as "object"  object value_API;

Answer (score 1):

Variable cannot be change it's type.
if you defined it as String, you can parse to Integer or double and so on.

Try Int32.Parse(String) and double(String)